# Update dataframe from another class in tkinter

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter, treeview

I would like to update a data frame displayed in tkinter getting the data from another class.

In my app, I have defined the frames using classes. By changing an input parameter in a class, the data frame should update in another class.

For instance, I select the multiplier in the `OptionMenu` within the class `Commands` and the column B in the data frame displayed in the class `Table` should be updated by this multiplier. But as I change the multiplier, the data frame does not update. I am using here `Treeview` to display the data frame.

[image]

As I start the app, the GUI appears like the following. The narrow stripe on the right is the empty data frame. I initialize it as empty and it remains empty even if I change the multiplier. While instead it should look like the previous screenshot.

[image]

Of course the full app is much more sophisticated, but here I simplify things for the sake of the question. Actually, the data frame contains many columns and the calculation is quite complex.

I try to pass the object through a controller method. For instance, in the class Table (which displays the data frame), I define:

```
class Table(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.controller = controller  # save the reference to the controller in each class

        ...
        get_metrics = self.controller.get_page(Commands)
        self.metrics = get_metrics.metrics
```

Where I (wrongly) suppose that the data frame `self.metrics` to be displayed in this frame gets updated by calling the function `get_page()` via the controller object. The function `get_page` gets the object `metrics` from the class `Commands` and is defined in the main class `sampleApp` as simple as:

```
def get_page(self, page_class):
    return self.frames[page_class]
```

The other class Commands contains the same method parent / controller to allow the objects to be passed among classes.

```
class Commands(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.controller = controller  # save the reference to the controller in each class

        self.metrics = pd.DataFrame()
```

In the class `Commands`, I initialize the data frame `self.metrics` as empty initially (but this is not important). Later in the class `Commands`, I update the data frame with the function `calculate_df`, which is a function that does not return anything and should remain so. Therefore, the data frame object calculated there is defined as `global`.

I update the data frame `self.metrics` in the class `Commands` using an `OptionMenu` method that calls the following two lines:

```
calculate_df(mult = self.mult)
self.metrics = df
```

Here `df` is `global` and I intentionally not define with the direct command `self.metrics = calculate_df(...)`.

The function `calculate_df` creates a data frame of two columns where the column B gets multiplied. For example with a multiplier of 2 `df` becomes:

```
   A  B
0  0  0
1  1  2
2  2  4
3  3  6
4  4  8
```

I post the full code in the following.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 20)
pd.set_option('display.width', 200)

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


def calculate_df(mult = 1.0):
    global df
    columns = [np.arange(5), np.arange(5) * mult]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.array(columns).T, columns=['A', 'B'])


class sampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "sampleApp")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        frame = Commands(parent=container, controller=self)
        self.frames[Commands] = frame
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
        # frame.pack()
        self.show_frame(Commands)

        frame = Table(parent=container, controller=self)
        self.frames[Table] = frame
        frame.grid(row=0, column=1)
        # frame.pack()
        self.show_frame(Table)


    def show_frame(self, frame_name):
        frame = self.frames[frame_name]
        frame.tkraise()

    def get_page(self, page_class):
        return self.frames[page_class]


class Table(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.controller = controller  # save the reference to the controller in each class

        table_frame = tk.Frame(self, bd=1, relief=tk.RIDGE)
        table_frame.pack(fill='x')

        get_metrics = self.controller.get_page(Commands)
        self.metrics = get_metrics.metrics

        # columns = [np.arange(5), np.arange(5) * 2]
        # df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.array(columns).T, columns=['A', 'B'])
        # self.metrics = df

        tv1 = ttk.Treeview(table_frame)
        tv1.pack()

        def display_metrics():
            tv1.delete(*tv1.get_children())
            tv1["column"] = list(self.metrics.columns)
            tv1["show"] = "headings"
            for column in tv1["columns"]:
                tv1.heading(column, text=column)  # set column heading

            df_rows = self.metrics.to_numpy().tolist()  # convert dataframe to list
            for row in df_rows:
                # inserts each list into the treeview.
                tv1.insert("", "end", values=row)

        display_metrics()


class Commands(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.controller = controller  # save the reference to the controller in each class

        self.metrics = pd.DataFrame()

        side_frame = tk.Frame(self, relief=tk.RIDGE)
        side_frame.pack()

        buttons_frame = tk.Frame(side_frame, bd=1, relief=tk.RIDGE)
        buttons_frame.pack(fill='x')

        Lab1 = tk.Label(buttons_frame, text="multiplier", anchor=tk.W)
        Lab1.grid(row=1, column=0)

        def set_multiplier(*args):
            self.mult = float(mult_var.get())
            print("multiplier", self.mult)

            calculate_df(mult = self.mult)
            self.metrics = df

        mult_var = tk.StringVar(self)
        mult_var.set('')
        mult_var.trace("w", set_multiplier)

        opt_mult = tk.OptionMenu(buttons_frame, mult_var, *[1, 2, 3, 4])
        opt_mult.grid(row=2, column=2, columnspan=1)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = sampleApp()
    app.geometry("+35+35")
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First change `tv1` to instance variable `self.tv1` and nested function `display_metrics()` to class function of `Table`.  Also pass the required *metrics* to `display_metrics()` as an argument.

Then you can call `Table.display_metrics()` directly inside nested function `set_multiplier()` inside `Commands` class:

```py
...
class Table(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.controller = controller  # save the reference to the controller in each class

        table_frame = tk.Frame(self, bd=1, relief=tk.RIDGE)
        table_frame.pack(fill='x')

        # changed tv1 to instance variable self.tv1
        self.tv1 = ttk.Treeview(table_frame, show="headings")
        self.tv1.pack()

    # change display_metrics() to class function with added argument metrics
    def display_metrics(self, metrics):
        self.tv1.delete(*self.tv1.get_children())
        self.tv1["column"] = list(metrics.columns)
        for column in self.tv1["columns"]:
            self.tv1.heading(column, text=column)  # set column heading

        df_rows = metrics.to_numpy().tolist()  # convert dataframe to list
        for row in df_rows:
            # inserts each list into the treeview.
            self.tv1.insert("", "end", values=row)


class Commands(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.controller = controller  # save the reference to the controller in each class

        self.metrics = pd.DataFrame()

        side_frame = tk.Frame(self, relief=tk.RIDGE)
        side_frame.pack()

        buttons_frame = tk.Frame(side_frame, bd=1, relief=tk.RIDGE)
        buttons_frame.pack(fill='x')

        Lab1 = tk.Label(buttons_frame, text="multiplier", anchor=tk.W)
        Lab1.grid(row=1, column=0)

        def set_multiplier(*args):
            self.mult = float(mult_var.get())
            print("multiplier", self.mult)

            calculate_df(mult = self.mult)
            self.metrics = df
            
            # update table
            self.controller.get_page(Table).display_metrics(self.metrics)

        mult_var = tk.StringVar(self)
        mult_var.set('')
        mult_var.trace("w", set_multiplier)

        opt_mult = tk.OptionMenu(buttons_frame, mult_var, *[1, 2, 3, 4])
        opt_mult.grid(row=2, column=2, columnspan=1)
...
```

Note that it is better to change nested function `set_multiplier()` to class method as well.

Comment: Thank you @acw1668. It was a good idea to change `display_metrics` to a class function. I have also changed `set_multiplier` to class method as well and it works very well. For the case of `set_multiplier` it works both ways: my original code and your suggestion. But what exactly is better when using the class method?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `static method` to achieve this.

You will have to read a bit about the topic.

But in short. You define a static method in Table class and then you can call that function in Commands class without initializing an instance of Table class. The static method can be called using `Table.my_method(value)`.